# Trying to convert a number prefixed with a non-numeric character into the number itself in MIPS

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips

I have the following string, "Q123" and would like to convert it to the number 123 in MIPS, but I am not sure how to do so.

I have loaded the string into the register t0,

```
li $v0, 8 #read a string into a0
la $a0, input1
la $t0, $a0
syscall
```

But I am not sure how to remove the first character from a string and then save it to one of the t registers in qtSPIM.

Comment: You don't keep strings in registers - you keep their addresses. And since what you've got in `$t0` is an address you can just do `addiu $t0,$t0,1` to make `$t0` point at "123".

Comment: could you explain what addiu does and why there needs to be a 1 at the end of the line?

Comment: It means `$t0 = $t0 + 1`